I have what I believe to be a '99 X-Games GT with serial# WYM9I4114. Can anyone help with info on this?

I've had the bike since new and could've sworn it was older than '99, but I may be wrong. I'm just looking to see what I have after all these years of hanging onto it. Any help is greatly appreciated!
(Stock Photo)

Is it a BMX ?  Something tells me its a BMX.   Could you please use [edit]  to add a clear and well lit photo of your bike.

Ok, I updated it.

The pictured bike does look like a 1999 GT X Games bike.
Here is a picture of another example for comparison.

BMXmuseum.com has several other examples.

it is a 1999. i read somewhere that all GT dealers received 1 of these as a limited run. i bought mine new at a GT dealer in Maine, paid $330. Still have it.
not sure how to post a picture of it...wish i could!
